# Impact of invalid File Handles during a File System Snapshot restore

Tags: filesystems, snapshot, nfs, filehandle

We have a scenario where we will restore the production FS with any earlier snapshot, while the FS is serving clients.

If the FH is not present in the snapshot that we are restoring from, then the client will see invalid FH? 
I'm trying to understand the impact of invalid FHs to the Client.
Eg: will the applications crash upon consistently receiving invalid FHs? 
Any other impact?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the implementation (and version) of the client.

Taking the canonical example these days - Linux - sometimes the application will receive an `ESTALE` error, and sometimes the client will re-perform the lookup to get a new file handle.

Quoting the [Linux NFS FAQ](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/):

> A client can recover when it encounters an ESTALE error during a
>   pathname resolution, but not during a READ or WRITE operation. An NFS
>   client prevents data corruption by notifying applications immediately
>   when a file has been replaced during a read or write request. After
>   all, it is usually catastrophic if an application writes to or reads
>   from the wrong file.
>
> Thus in general, to recover from an ESTALE error, an application must
>   close the file or directory where the error occurred, and reopen it so
>   the NFS client can resolve the pathname again and retrieve the new
>   file handle.
>
> Older Linux NFS clients do not recover from an ESTALE error, even
>   during pathname resolution. In the 2.6.12 kernel and later, the Linux
>   VFS layer can redrive pathname resolution when an ESTALE is
>   encountered to recover appropriately.